# Powershell - ForEach loop running twice on the same path instead of moving on next one

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am looking to move files from various paths to E:\backups\folder1\export, E:\Backups\folder2\backups, E:\backups\folder3\export and using below code...but strangely it runs twice on the same path and doesn't move to next path and duplicates the output too.

```
Cls
  $date = Get-Date  -Format "yyyMMdd_hhmmss"
  #$sourcePath = "C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA\export\"
  #$destPath = "E:\Backup\Jira\export"
  $config = Import-Csv -Path 'E:\Backup\Scripts\Atlassian_Backups.csv'
  #Write-Output $config
  Start-Transcript -Path E:\Backup\Logs\Atlassian_backupMove.log
  foreach ($item in $config) 
{
Write-Host "Moving all files in '$($sourcePath)' to '$($destPath)'"
$fileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "$($sourcePath)" -File)  
#Write-Output $fileList
if ($filelist.count -gt 0)
    {
    Write-host $filelist.Count
  ForEach($file in $fileList)
  {
    try {
    #Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ((Split-Path 
    $file.FullName).Replace("$($sourcePath)",$destPath)) -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destPath -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Format-table
    }
    catch{
      Write-Warning "Unable to move '$($file.FullName)' to '$(((Split-Path 
    $file.FullName).Replace("$($sourcePath)",$destPath)))': $($_)"
      return
     } 
  }
}
}
Stop-Transcript
Rename-Item E:\Backup\Logs\Atlassian_backupMove.log 
E:\Backup\Logs\Atlassian_backupMove_$date.log
write-host Log File has been created and  renamed to Atlassian_backupMove_$date.log'
```

Comment: Are there duplicate paths on the csv you are importing from? also `$sourcePath` and `$destPath` are commented out, be careful as these variables persist when using Powershell ISE.

Comment: hi @Otter - I am using csv file which has few paths and gave the same names to title line. so, as soon as it finishes the first line it should move to next line. however I am not concerned about what files types are at $sourcePath.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and expected output? Also please give a small extract of the csv so we have something to work from?

Comment: have managed to review my code... and managed to fix..
 try {
        #Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ((Split-Path $file.FullName).Replace("$($sourcePath)",$destPath)) -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $item.destPath -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop | Format-table
        }
        catch{
          Write-Warning "Unable to move '$($file.FullName)' to '$(((Split-Path $file.FullName).Replace("$($item.sourcePath)",$item.destPath)))': $($_)"
          return
         }

Answer (score 0):

below was changed in my code and worked well.

```
{#Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ((Split-Path 
$file.FullName).Replace("$($sourcePath)",$destPath)) -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $item.destPath -Verbose -Force - 
ErrorAction Stop | Format-table } catch{ Write-Warning "Unable to move 
'$($file.FullName)' to '$(((Split-Path 
$file.FullName).Replace("$($item.sourcePath)",$item.destPath)))': $($_)" return 
}
```